# spring cache, TTL unles service is down

Tags: java, spring, caching

I have an interesting task where I need to cache the results of my method, which is really simple with spring cache abstraction

```
@Cachable(...)
public String getValue(String key){
    return restService.getValue(key);
}
```

The **restService.getValue()** targets a REST service, which can be answering or not if the end point is down.

I need to set a specific TTL for the cache value, lets say 5 minutes, but in case if the server is down I need to return the last value, even if it extends 5 minutes.

I was thinking about having a second cachable method which have no TTL and always returns the last value, it would be called from getValue if restService returns nothing, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been interested in doing this for a while too.  Sorry to say, I have not found any trivial way of doing this. Spring will not do this for you, it's more a question of whether what cache implementation spring is wrapping can do it. I assume you are using the EhCache implementation.  Unfortunately this functionality does not come out the box as far as I know.

There are various ways one can achieve something similar depending on your problem

1) use an eternal cache time and have a second class Thread which periodically loops over the cached data refreshing it. I have not done this exactly, but the Thread class would need to have to look something like this:

```
@Autowired    
EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager; 
...
//in the infinite loop
            List keys = ((Ehcache) ehCacheCacheManager.getCache("test").getNative                Cache()).getKeys();
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
                Object o = keys.get(i);
                Ehcache ehcache = (Ehcache)ehCacheCacheManager.getCache("test").getNativeCache()
                Element item = (ehcache).get(o);

                //get the data based on some info in the value, and if no exceptions         
                ehcache.put(new Element(element.getKey(), newValue));

            }
```

- benefits are this is very fast for the @Cacheable caller, downside is your server might get more hits than neccessary

2) You could make a CacheListener to listen to the eviction event, store the data temporarily.  And should the server call fail, use that data and return from the method.

the ehcache.xml

```
    <cacheEventListenerFactory class="caching.MyCacheEventListenerFactory"/>

  </cache>
</ehcache>
```

The factory:
    import net.sf.ehcache.event.CacheEventListener;
    import net.sf.ehcache.event.CacheEventListenerFactory;
    import java.util.Properties;

```
public class MyCacheEventListenerFactory extends CacheEventListenerFactory {
  @Override
  public CacheEventListener createCacheEventListener(Properties properties) {
    return new CacheListener();
  } 
}
```

The Pseudo-implementation
    import net.sf.ehcache.CacheException;
    import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;
    import net.sf.ehcache.Element;
    import net.sf.ehcache.event.CacheEventListener;

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class CacheListener implements CacheEventListener  {
   //prob bad practice to use a global static here - but its just for demo purposes
   public static ConcurrentHashMap myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

   @Override
   public void notifyElementPut(Ehcache ehcache, Element element) throws CacheException {
     //we can remove it since the put happens after a method return
     myMap.remove(element.getKey());
   }

   @Override
   public void notifyElementExpired(Ehcache ehcache, Element element) {
    //expired item, we should store this
    myMap.put(element.getKey(), element.getValue());
    }
 //....
}
```

- A challenge here is that the key is not very useful, you might need to store something about the key in the returned value to be able to pick it up if the server call fails. This feels a bit hacky, and I have not determined if this is exactly bullet proof.  It might need some testing.

3) A lot of effort but works:

```
@Cacheable("test")
public MyObject getValue(String data) {
    try {
        MyObject result = callServer(data);
        storeResultSomewhereLikeADatabase(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return getStoredResult(data);
    }
}
```

a Pro here is that it will work between server restarts, and you can extend it simply to allow shared caches between clustered servers.
I had a version in an 12 clustered environment where each one checked the database first to see if any other cluster had got the "expensive" data first
and then reused that rather than make the server call.

A slight variant would also be to use a second @Cacheable method together with @CachePut  rather than a DB to store the data. But this would mean doubling up in memory usage.  That might be acceptable depending on your result sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use spel to change the used cache (one using ttl and the second not)  if the condition (is the service up?) is true or false, I've never used spel this way (I used it to change the key based on some request params) but I think it could work

```
@Cacheable(value = "T(com.xxx.ServiceChecker).checkService()",...)
```

where checkService() is a static method that returns the name of the cache that should be used

Comment: this sounds like there are 2 calls needed to the target server, one to determine if server is up and second to get the actual data. 2 calls means that the server might go down in the middle.

Comment: maybe using some custom logic inside that method could help a lot, but at the end it's not a big improvement respect what you suggested as the main alternative in your question :(